# how to test event of a web application with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to test a web application.
I have an HTML stepper with forms that contain dropdowns and buttons (GET, POST requests)
I still cant understand how to test a specific event..
for example lets say I have to select a department from my dropdown and then to pop up a window with a list of subdepartments (checkboxes)..
Where shall I find the HTTPS request urls to use them in the JMeter samplers?  From developer tools/Network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If selecting a dropdown triggers a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) (i.e. it's some form of [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) call) you can replicate it using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler  (and most probably [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)) so JMeter will send exactly the same request as the browser does (you might need to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic values)

Basically all you need to do is to configure JMeter to produce the same network footprint as the real browser does so cross-check the request payload from the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) with what you see in JMeter's [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

Also be aware that it is possible to record the requests generated by browser using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), see [Recording Tests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#script-recorder) user manual chapter for more details.

Comment: OK I understood. Thank you